# master config file to set tab=4 spaces for every editor at once

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, text-editor, nano

I've had to edit configuration files for all of my various editors (emacs, vim, nano, etc.) to have a tab spacing equal to 4 spaces instead of the seemingly default 8. Is there a more elegant way? Some master file I can point them all to in order to use the same tabs/spaces settings for all of them?

Comment: In Emacs, we usually consider that `tab-width = 8` is universally true and should never be changed.  If you want your cursor to move by 4 columns when you hit the `tab` key, that's perfectly fine, and Emacs lets you do that (e.g. by customizing `tab-stop-list`) because in Emacs, the `tab` key and the `TAB` character are two very different things, and more often than not the `tab` key does not insert a `TAB` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use http://editorconfig.org (you need to place .editorconfig in each project)

Comment: Beautiful! That's perfect I had no Idea that existed. I just put the .editorconfig file in my home directory so every project uses the same file, will that cause any issues?

Comment: I guess no :) But take in mind that local .editorconfig of projects still can override your settings